# How to validate props with propTypes having defaultProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-props, react-proptypes

Earlier when we were not using defaultProps, we use to get warning in
the console that this props is not passed. But after configuring the
props signature using defaultProps we don't get any errors as such. So, how to configure both to work as expected?

```
/* Default Props */
MyApp.defaultProps = {
  data: {
    totalCount: 123
  },
  name: 'john doe'
};

/* Proptypes */
MyApp.proptypes = {
  data: {
    totalCount: Proptypes.number.isRequired
  },
  name: Proptypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Comment: You have `.isRequired` so you need to provide prop for value and you are doing it by `defaultProps` (but also because of that it should not be required anyway :) )

Answer (score 0):

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

You must use

```
class test { 
    static propTypes = { 
        optionalBool: PropTypes.bool,
        requiredProperty: PropTypes.number.isRequired
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: And what exactly to explain?

Comment: Can you update my question query how to use this `static propTypes`?

Comment: Michael this won’t work or not in the context what I am referring to. All this are react components not basic classes and the way u have shown is not different than what I am trying to do :)

Answer (score 0):

You are already doing it correctly, the problem you had before is that when the component was initialized, it had null values for its props, so you get run time warning expecting some null value props, default props sets that value even on initial component mount. :)

Comment: its `undefined` not `null`

Comment: but you did pass both those props right? If you did not then that is another issue and that you need to remove these. You defined these props to be required so having a default prop would be needed to fix the error, if you dont need a default prop and that those props are nullable then you need to remove the .isRequired()

Comment: I'm not OP. I just wanted to point that default value of unpassed prop is `undefined` rather than `null`.

Comment: See let the default props set but I need to handle the warning, is there any possibility to handle both ?